# Creating a website that doubles as an app using Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I've been creating apps using AppSheet where an app is usable from both a desktop computer as well as Android and iOS mobile devices. We recently became disillusioned with the AppSheet platform due to bugs that they refused to fix, and so decided to move on to Codename One. My only question is, will an app I create on Codename One be usable from both a desktop and an Android/iOS device?

Thanks.
Tiffany

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you have a pro account. Codename Ones desktop support requires a pro level subscription.

iOS/Android work fine in the free subscription too.

Notice that the web support for Codename one (running in the browser) requires the enterprise level subscription.